# When autovaccum will analyze?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, transaction, autovacuum

Let's suppose that a table `foo` became eligible for autovacuum analyze, e.g. I have inserted a number of rows into `foo` that exceeds `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor * number of rows + autovacuum_analyze_threshold` effective threshold. I can't figure out which are the conditions that should be satisfied in order to have autovacuum performing the analyze on `foo`.

Will autovacuum analyze run for table `foo` only if there are no transactions? Or it can run even during active transactions with the conditions that: (1) no transaction is reading a previous version of table `foo` and (2) the autovacuum analyze can gain `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` lock on table `foo`?

These questions are related to particular case. I peform a significant number of INSERTs into `foo` in one transaction and then some UPDATEs on `foo` in a second transaction. I need the autovacuum analyze to run before the 2nd transaction in order to have an up to date statistics of `foo` for my query planner better estimates. Are there a way to guarantee that the autovacuum analyze will run before the 2nd transaction? Maybe to sleep (I'm running both transactions from Java app) couple of milliseconds between transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is correct.

The number of live rows is taken from the `reltuples` column in `pg_class`, and the result of the formula is compared to `n_mod_since_analyze` from `pg_stat_all_tables`.

Note that `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` and `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` can be overridden by storage parameters on th table.

If all available autovacuum workers are running (`autovacuum_max_workers`), you may have to wait.

Analyze only takes an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on the table (it only reads), so it can run concurrently with almost anything. Like a `SELECT` statement, it will see the rows that are visible to it.

If you need a table to be analyzed between an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE`, don't wait for autoanalyze to run. Explicitly start `ANALYZE` on the table.

Comment: To analyze a table, one must ordinarily be the table's owner. My application uses a database user that is not the owner of the tables. Of course its not a problem to change the ownership, but I'm interested if there is a solution where I can avoid explicit start of `ANALYZE`?

Comment: You could use a `SECURITY DEFINER` function that runs `ANALYZE`. That is harmless if you set `search_path = ''` on the function.

Comment: What implications `search_path = ''` have?

Comment: It makes the function body independent of the current setting of `search_path` in the session and prevents [privilege escalation attacks](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).